# Remove row from one tab if corresponding coordinate from another tab overlap

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframe

**Tab1**

```
Species      start  end 
G1:Sp1       5      30
G1:Sp1       60     90 
G1:Sp2       50     120
```

**Tab2**

```
Species start end
G1:SP1   1     4
G1:SP1   30    59 
G1:SP1   70    93
G1:SP2   48    110 
G1:SP2   50    120
G1:SP2   56    124 
G1:SP2   130   170
```

And I would like to remove from **Tab2** each `Species` where the `start` and `end` coordinates overlaps with the corresponding `Species` coordinates in **Tab1**.

**What I mean by overlap ?:**

Let's say I have in **Tab1**:

```
Species      start  end 
G1:Sp1       5      30
```

Then if a `G1:SP1` in **Tab2** have the following `start` and `end`:

```
start end 
1     5  (does not overlap with 5-30)
5     27 (does overlap with 5-30, from inside) 
5     30 (does overlap with 5-30, exactly the same coordinate)
10    27 (does overlap with 5-30, from inside) 
10    33 (does overlap with 5-30, from inside and outside right)
2     25 (does overlap with 5-30, from inside and outside left)
33    50 (does not overlap with 5-30)
```

In the exemple then :

```
G1:SP1   1     4   <- does not overlap (I keep)
G1:SP1   30    59  <- does not overlap (I keep) 
G1:SP1   70    93  <- does overlap with (**60-90**, I remove) 
G1:SP2   48    110 <- does overlap with (**50-120**, I remove) 
G1:SP2   50    120 <- does overlap with (**50-120**, I remove) 
G1:SP2   56    124 <- does not overlap (I keep)
G1:SP2   130   170 <- does not overlap (I keep)
```

I should then get:

```
Species start end
G1:SP1   1     4
G1:SP1   30    59 
G1:SP2   56    124 
G1:SP2   130   170
```

Here are the data in dic format if it can help :

> > > tab1.to_dict()

```
{'Species': {0: 'G1:Sp1', 1: 'G1:Sp1', 2: 'G1:Sp2'}, 'start': {0: 5, 1: 60, 2: 50}, 'end ': {0: 30, 1: 90, 2: 120}}
```

> > > tab2.to_dict()

```
{'Species': {0: 'G1:SP1', 1: 'G1:SP1', 2: 'G1:SP1', 3: 'G1:SP2', 4: 'G1:SP2', 5: 'G1:SP2', 6: 'G1:SP2'}, 'start': {0: 1, 1: 30, 2: 70, 3: 48, 4: 50, 5: 56, 6: 130}, 'end': {0: 4, 1: 59, 2: 93, 3: 110, 4: 120, 5: 124, 6: 170}}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by overlap? It is unclear to me. You could try and be more explicit instead of saying 'overlap'.

Comment: Added a part to explain it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

```
tab1['key'] = tab1['Species'].str.upper()
tab2['key'] = tab2['Species'].str.upper()

tab = tab2.reset_index().merge(tab1, on='key', 
                               how='left', suffixes=['', '_y'])

is_overlap = tab.eval('(start >= start_y and start <= end_y)'
                      'or (end >= start_y and end <= end_y)')

idx = tab.loc[~is_overlap, 'index']
tab2_new = tab2[tab2.index.isin(idx)]
```

**Step by step details:**

1. Transform the column `Species` in both the dataframes to create a new `key` column which will act as a case insensitive merge key

```
>>> tab1
  Species  start  end     key
0  G1:Sp1      5   30  G1:SP1
1  G1:Sp1     60   90  G1:SP1
2  G1:Sp2     50  120  G1:SP2

>>> tab2
  Species  start  end     key
0  G1:SP1      1    4  G1:SP1
1  G1:SP1     30   59  G1:SP1
2  G1:SP1     70   93  G1:SP1
3  G1:SP2     48  110  G1:SP2
4  G1:SP2     50  120  G1:SP2
5  G1:SP2     56  124  G1:SP2
6  G1:SP2    130  170  G1:SP2
```

2. Reset the index of `tab2` then left merge with `tab1`

```
>>> tab

   index Species  start  end     key Species_y  start_y  end_y
0      0  G1:SP1      1    4  G1:SP1    G1:Sp1        5     30
1      0  G1:SP1      1    4  G1:SP1    G1:Sp1       60     90
2      1  G1:SP1     30   59  G1:SP1    G1:Sp1        5     30
3      1  G1:SP1     30   59  G1:SP1    G1:Sp1       60     90
4      2  G1:SP1     70   93  G1:SP1    G1:Sp1        5     30
5      2  G1:SP1     70   93  G1:SP1    G1:Sp1       60     90
6      3  G1:SP2     48  110  G1:SP2    G1:Sp2       50    120
7      4  G1:SP2     50  120  G1:SP2    G1:Sp2       50    120
8      5  G1:SP2     56  124  G1:SP2    G1:Sp2       50    120
9      6  G1:SP2    130  170  G1:SP2    G1:Sp2       50    120
```

3. Evaluate the condition which checks for the overlaps in two dataframes

```
>>> is_overlap
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
5     True
6     True
7     True
8     True
9    False
dtype: bool
```

4. Select the indices which does not satisfy the `is_overlap` condition

```
>>> idx

0    0
1    0
3    1
4    2
9    6
Name: index, dtype: int64
```

5. Filter the rows in `tab2` using the above indices

```
>>> tab2_new

  Species  start  end     key
0  G1:SP1      1    4  G1:SP1
1  G1:SP1     30   59  G1:SP1
2  G1:SP1     70   93  G1:SP1
6  G1:SP2    130  170  G1:SP2
```

Comment: Hello, I get the following error message  : ```name 'end_y' is not defined```

Comment: Check the column names in your original dataframes make sure they are `start` and `end`

Comment: Indeed there were a space in the title, thank you